# php url explode

Tags: php, arrays, url, explode

I am wanting to grab my product from my url. For example:

```
http://www.website.com/product-category/iphone
```

I am wanting to grab the iphone and that is fine with my code but I have a dropdown to sort products and which clicked will change the url and add a query like:

```
http://www.website.com/product-category/iphone?orderby=popularity
http://www.website.com/product-category/iphone?orderby=new
http://www.website.com/product-category/iphone?orderby=price
http://www.website.com/product-category/iphone?orderby=price-desc
```

My current code is

```
$r = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
$r = explode('/', $r);
$r = array_filter($r);
$r = array_merge($r, array()); 

$endofurl = $r[1];
echo $endofurl;
```

How is it possible to grab the iphone section all the time.

Cheers

Comment: Will the product name always follow /product-category/ ?

Answer (score 7):

You can use PHP's [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url) function to split the URL for you and then access the `path` parameter and get the end of it:

```
$r = parse_url($url);
$endofurl = substr($r['path'], strrpos($r['path'], '/'));
```

This will parse the URL and then take a "sub-string" of the URL starting from the last-found `/` in the path.

You can alternatively use `explode('/')` as you're currently doing on the path:

```
$path = explode($r['path']);
$endofurl = $path[count($path) - 1];
```

**UPDATE** (using [`strrchr()`](http://php.net/strrchr), pointed out by @x4rf41):
A shorter method of obtaining the end of the string, opposed to `substr()` + `strrpos()` is to use `strrchr()`:

```
$endofurl = strrchr($r['path'], '/');
```

If you take advantage of `parse_url()`'s option parameters, you can also get *just the path* by using `PHP_URL_PATH` like
$r = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);

Or, the shortest method:

```
$endofurl = strrchr(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH), '/');
```

Comment: even shorter would be `$endofurl = strrchr(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH),'/');`

Answer (score 5):

If you want to retrieve the last element of the array, you can use the [end](http://php.net/end) function. The rest of your code seems to be working.

```
$endofurl = end($r);
```

You could also leverage [parse_url](http://php.net/parse_url) and [strrchr](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrchr.php) functions to make it more concise:

```
$endofurl = strrchr(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH), '/');
```

Answer (score 4):

Just figured it out.This now works with

```
$r = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
$r = explode('/', $r);
$r = array_filter($r);
$r = array_merge($r, array()); 
$r = preg_replace('/\?.*/', '', $r);

$endofurl = $r[1];
echo $endofurl;
```