# PHP replace the very last part of a url

Tags: php, replace, preg-replace

I have the following url - this url is not always the same though, but will always end the same:

```
$thumbnail_url = 'http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/552yWya5RgY/hqdefault.jpg'
```

using php I'd like to replace `hqdefault.jpg` with `maxresdefault.jpg`

so the new thumbnail would look something like this:

```
$hq_thumbnail_url = 'http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/552yWya5RgY/maxresdefault.jpg'
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Just use `dirname()`

Comment: Thanks @Rizier123 - i'm not sure how though

Comment: Well you get everything except `hqdefault.jpg` so you can just append `maxresdefault.jpg` to the return value of `dirname()`

Comment: Str_replace? Why make it complex? You know the start name and end name. There is nothing "regex" in it

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15118047/php-url-explode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

str_replace() is probably your most simple approach...

```
$thumbnail_url = 'http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/552yWya5RgY/hqdefault.jpg';

$hq_thumbnail_url = str_replace('hqdefault.jpg', 'maxresdefault.jpg', $thumbnail_url);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it, and it will work even if `hqdefault.jpg`   isn't at the end of the url :

```
$url = 'http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/552yWya5RgY/hqdefault.jpg';  // Url you want to change
$newImage = 'newimage.jpg';                                 // New filename 

$splitUrl = explode('/', $url); // Split the url at each '/' occurence
$splitUrl[5] = $newImage;       // Change the old filename (hqdefault.jpg) with the new one

$newUrl = implode('/',$splitUrl);  // Reform the url, but this time, with the new filename.
echo $newUrl;                      // Here's the modified url
```