# Split URL by PHP

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

Hi I'm a newbie in PHP and for my home project I need help where I want to split values with in a URL.

`$url = "http://localhost/Sub/Key/Key_XYZ_1234.php";`

url can also be:

`$url = "http://localhost/Sub/Key/Key-XYZ-1234.php";`

key value can be "ABC-TT" or "ABC_TT" or just "ABC"

intended result
`$v1 = value of Key;`
`$v2 = value of XYZ;`
`$v3 = value of 1234;`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php url explode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15118047/php-url-explode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a combination of [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php), [`basename`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) and [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php). We use `preg_split` so we can deal with the separator being either a `-` or an `_`:

```
$url = "http://localhost/Sub/Key/Key-XYZ-1234.php";
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$file = basename($path, '.php');
list($v1, $v2, $v3) = preg_split('/[-_]/', $file);
echo "\$v1 = $v1\n\$v2 = $v2\n\$v3 = $v3\n";
```

Output:

```
$v1 = Key 
$v2 = XYZ 
$v3 = 1234
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/llku4)

Comment: Hi Nick,  Thank you for the reply... it indeed work. Can you also help me with this url as well "$url = "http://localhost/Sub/index.php?a1=key/key-XYZ-1234.php";" with same reply.    Thanks in advance

Comment: @Maddy that's a bit trickier... what parts of `index.php?a1=key/key-XYZ-1234.php` do you want to keep?

Comment: Key, XYZ, 1234 only

Comment: @Maddy I think changing the `$path` definition to `$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH) . parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);` should work

Comment: Thanks Nick, your code worked as desired... you are the saver ... :) appreciate your help.

Comment: @Maddy no worries. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Something like....

```
//this is psuedo code, but you can look up the function names to see how to use them

$path=parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$sep="-";
if(strpos($path,$sep)===false){
   $sep="_";
}
$pieces=explode($sep,$path);
$key=$pieces[0];
$a=$pieces[1];
$nums=$peices[2];
```