# An incrementing function in php going wrong

Tags: php, mysql, function, max, increment

I have prepared a php function which gets the MAX value in a row, then adds '1' to the number. So that whenever I register a new stage, it prepares the MAX value for the next stage to be registered. Everything goes fine with the function so long as the MAX value has not reached number '10'. When it gets to '10', then the MAX value does not change, and no matter I add a new stage or not, the value stays at 10. 
May you please help me what's wrong here. 
 here is the code:

```
$query = "SELECT MAX(pstage_num) as latest_level FROM pstage 
                               WHERE course = :course";
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
            $course= sanitize($course);
            $stmt->bindParam("course", $course);
            $stmt->execute();
            $outcome = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return intval($outcome['latest_level'])+1;
```

and this is my sanitize() function:

```
function sanitize($in = null) {
    return filter_var($in, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);
}
```

Comment: Can you show the table definition for `pstage`? More specifically the definition of the column `pstage_num`.

Comment: i can't undestand why you cannot just mark the pstage_num as autoincrement in your table definition...

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? This does look pretty strange. And why do you sanitize your data through own code **and** prepared statements?

Comment: This is all the weirdo with a newbie, bro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is because `pstage_num` in your table is defined as a character type (probably `VARCHAR`). When you attempt to take the `MAX` of '9' and '10', you get '9' (see [this dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ee9e636871403b5e5cbca5bf23c820d1)) because **as a string** '9' is greater than '10'. So even if you insert values all the way up to 89, you will still get '9' as the maximum value. You need to change the type of your column to `INT` to make this code work, e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE pstage MODIFY COLUMN pstage_num INT
```

After which the code will work (see [this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6a92d0e7b7b09239410fc5ca5fce6a67))

Comment: Special Appreciations !!! Millions of thanks. Learned something new. Wish you the best.

Comment: Dear Nick, since my reputation is less than 15, I am not authorized to vote, you know that. Had I had more reputations, I would have voted you up without you asking me to. Anyhow, I would like to thank you again.

Comment: @H.M. I indeed know you can't vote, but you can **close** a question by marking an answer accepted, which is checking the mark under the up/down vote buttons. See for example the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55270823/split-url-by-php/55270993#comment97325430_55270993) which is marked accepted even though the poster has less reputation than you.

Comment: Done. I did it dear Nick.